# socket.io socket disconnects after 60 secs after reconnection

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

In a disconnect event, i connect to the socket again by using socket.socket.reconnect(). A socket works fine until a reconnection. After reconnection i see the socket gets disconnected every 60 seconds. 
Here is my connection code:

```
socket = io.connect("https://website.com:8080", 
{'close timeout':'3',
'force new connection':true});
```

Here is what i do in a disconnect:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
alert("disconnect");
socket.socket.reconnect();
});
```

Now if i fire a socket.disconnect() on client side, the socket keeps disconnecting and reconnecting every 60 seconds. 
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Found a solution? I have same problem with underlying socket connection of PeerJS - server, while my socket.io connections remains more or less stable.